# How to populate JTable from database on button event

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

I have a text box that allows users to put in select type queries with the idea that when they click a button the result of the select statement will be shown in a JTable. I don't get any errors but also nothing is shown in the textPane when my button is pressed. The I have is below:

```
public class Console {

    String myquery="";

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Console window = new Console();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public Console() {
        initialize();
    }


    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 950, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextArea textAreaQuery = new JTextArea();
            JTable table_ResQues = new JTable();
            JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Execute");
            btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    String connectDB = "jdbc:ucanaccess:///Users/sebastianzeki/Documents/PhysJava/Physiology.mdb;";
                    System.out.println("Connection To Database Made");
                    Connection conn = null;

                        try {
                            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectDB);
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Statement st = null;
                        try {
                            st = conn.createStatement();
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                         myquery=textAreaQuery.getText();
                        String stg2 = "Select "+myquery;
                        ResultSet rs = null;
                        try {
                            rs = st.executeQuery(stg2);
                            table_ResQues.setModel(getDataFromDatabase);
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
}
```

and the code to build the model:

```
  public TableModel getDataFromDatabase()
{
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(5, 5);
    model.setValueAt("Hard", 0, 0);
    model.setValueAt("Coded", 1, 1);
    model.setValueAt("Data", 2, 2);

    return model;
}
    }
```

Comment: There is no way to tell from this code whether your table, text area, etc are being displayed at all. Also, don't use `Vector`

Comment: They are being displayed just not populated

Comment: `but also nothing is shown in the textPane` - I assume you mean "JTable". The basic code looks reasonable. You are using the `setModel(...)` method to update the table which is correct assuming the table has been added to a JScrollPane and the scrollPane added to the frame. So assuming the ResultSetMetaData and ResultSet actually return some data it should work.

Comment: I have no scrollPane. I intend to use it but not until I can see data. I that an issue. And yes I meant JTable- Ive edited

Comment: @pvg, `Also, don't use Vector` - the DefaultTableModel stores the data in a Vector, so yes the code should be using a Vector.

Comment: @SebastianZeki there is just no way to test any of your code, you should write an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `I have no scrollPane` - well you need a scroll pane to see the column headers of the table, but the first step is to verify the data returned from the SQL query. You also need to verify that you don't have two references to your table. One that is an instance variable and one that is a local variable. You need to update the table that if visible on the frame.

Comment: @camickr right. better would be 'don't use DefaultTableModel`

Comment: but not having a  scrollPane wont stop me seeing the data will it? Just trying to keep it as simple as possible for the moment

Comment: @pvg, then you need to create a custom TableModel and that could introduce addition errors. The DefaultTableModel is perfectly fine for displaying data from a database. You can customize it later once the basic code is working. Don't complicate the process if you don't have to.

Comment: @camickr `AbstractTableModel` covers that stuff nicely.

Comment: @pvg, the AbstractTableModel does not cover that. You need to implement all the methods to store the data. That is where you would introduce problems. Keep the code simple until that basic problem has been solved!!!

Comment: The SQL is verified so the database connection and resultSet works fine

Comment: @camickr no you need to implement three methods. You have to provide storage for DefaultTableModel as well, just as the code above does. It's harder to follow and uses legacy classes. This is a silly argument and unrelated to the question but generally, DefaultTableModel should be avoided and doesn't really offer any benefits.

Comment: OK Im just going to stay with DefaultTableModel for the moment - Ill learn about the AbstractTableModel later but as regards populating the JTable? Is it to do with the fact that population happens in a button event?

Comment: @png, and if you implement those methods incorrectly, the table will be messed up. There is no need to create a custom TableModel when first learning how to use a JTable. It will do the job and simplify the code so you can concentrate on other things. Trying to use a custom TableModel will NOT solve this problem and is off topic!!!

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to display the results?

Comment: You haven't posted your complete code but as I suggested you have an instance variable and a local variable for your JTable. Get rid of the local variable. If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. The is first create a simple program that displays hard coded data in a table. Then once that is working you know your table references are correct and you replace the hardcoded data with your SQL query.

Comment: i have edited the code to provide a SSCCE

Comment: @SebastianZeki, no you have not provided a SSCCE. 1) The code still contains SQL which we cannot execute since we don't have access to your database. 2) you still have two table references.

Comment: Ive removed the local variable see edit- but I have no idea how to provide a testable database for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ive removed the local variable

No, you removed the instance variable. Did you actually try this with your real code or just edit the question?

> I have no idea how to provide a testable database for this question

I already suggested you create a method to simplify the logic. Somethng like:

```
public TableModel getDataFromDatabase()
{
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(5, 5);
    model.setValueAt("Hard", 0, 0);
    model.setValueAt("Coded", 1, 1);
    model.setValueAt("Data", 2, 2);

    return model;
}
```

Then in your ActionListener you simple do something like:

```
table_ResQues.setModel( getDataFromDataBase() );
```

Once you get this basic logic working you move the SQL logic into the `getDataFromDatabase()` method.

So now you create your SSCCE showing how you actually create the frame and add the components to the frame. The code should be compilable and executable.

Edit:

You have been told to display a table is a scrollpane. It is no extra effort to do this. Instead of using:

```
panel.add(table);
```

you use:

```
panel.add( new JScrollPane( table ) );
```

I would also suggest that to test your layout you can use code like the following to display a dummy table:

```
//JTable table_ResQues = new JTable();
JTable table_ResQues = new JTable(5,5);
```

Then when you use the setModel() method, only the data is affected, not the layout of the table.

> I cant help but feel this is a fireTableDataChanged problem though.

I doubt it. That method is invoked by the TableModel when you change the data in the model. It is not used in this case because you are using the `setModel(...)` method. This will cause the table to repaint() itself automatically.

Comment: OK edited. I cant help but feel this is a fireTableDataChanged problem though. I think the JTable is populated with nothing when the frame loads up and then when the button is pressed it has no way of knowing that the data has changed so nothing new is added?

Comment: You completely miss the point of the getDataFromDatabase() method. There is no need for any SQL code at all.

Comment: OK. Looks like I just had to add it to a JscrollPane. Thanks @camickr

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to your problem. I have retained your variable names though not all of them followed Java conventions. I think all you wanted was that the user would type SQL query in `JTextArea` and see the result of the query in a `JTable`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Console {
   private JFrame frame; 
   private JTextArea textAreaQuery; 
   private JTable table_ResQues;
   private JButton btnNewButton;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Console window = new Console();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Console() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame("SQL Query");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 950, 800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    textAreaQuery = new JTextArea();
    btnNewButton = new JButton("Execute");
    table_ResQues = new JTable();

    JPanel queryPanel=new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); // holds JTextArea and JButton

    queryPanel.add(new JScrollPane(textAreaQuery), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    btnPanel.add(btnNewButton);
    queryPanel.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);       

    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, queryPanel,
            new JScrollPane(table_ResQues));
    splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
    splitPane.setDividerLocation(150);
    frame.setContentPane(splitPane);        
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) {                   
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }*/
            String connectDB = "jdbc:ucanaccess:///Users/sebastianzeki/Documents/PhysJava/Physiology.mdb;";         
            Connection conn = null;
            Statement st = null;
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectDB);
                //conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/cwcx", "root", "admin");// MySQL connection
                st = conn.createStatement();
                System.out.println("Connection To Database Made");
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            String myquery = textAreaQuery.getText();
            if(myquery.endsWith(";")){
                myquery=myquery.substring(0, myquery.length()-1);
            }
            ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                rs = st.executeQuery(myquery);
                // extract column information
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData(); 
                int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                List<String> columnData = new ArrayList<String>(columnCount);
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                    columnData.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
                }
                // sql result data
                List<List<Object>> rowData = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    List<Object> row = new ArrayList<Object>(columnCount);
                    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                        row.add(rs.getObject(i + 1));
                    }
                    rowData.add(row);
                }                   
                table_ResQues.setModel(new ListTableModel(rowData, columnData));                    
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, e1.getMessage(), "SQL Exception", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                if(rs!=null){
                    try {
                        rs.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {                         
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(st!=null){
                    try {
                        st.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {                         
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(conn!=null){
                    try {
                        conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {                         
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });

}

// this table model is created from two dimensional List rowData and single dimensional List columnData
private static class ListTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;        
    private List<List<Object>> rowData;     
    private List<String> columnData;        
    public ListTableModel(List<List<Object>> rowData, List<String> columnData) {            
        this.rowData = rowData;
        this.columnData = columnData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {          
        return rowData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {           
        return columnData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {       
        return rowData.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {           
        return columnData.get(column);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        Object obj=rowData.get(0).get(columnIndex);
        return obj.getClass();
    }       
  }

}
```

On my system, I have tested it with `MySQL` database. But I have commented out that part. You may try this on your system without any modification. Please do tell me whether you wanted to achieve this solution or not.

Comment: @SebastianZeki Since this answer is not a solution to your problem, I am going to remove it.